# How do I put a horizontal line/border right in the middle of a table row?

Tags: html, css

Essentially I would like to apply a `bottom-border`, but rather than being in the bottom of the cell, I want it to be in the dead center.

How do I do that with CSS & HTML only (and using no graphics)?

So imagine the height of the cell/row is 50px, and width = 100px, I would like the line to be width = 100px, and it to be at 25px height in the row/cell.

Thanks.

P.S. Imagine something like the cross out functionality for font - but for an empty space (if that makes any sense).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

perhaps put an `<hr>` in the cell and then use CSS to give it an absolute position.

Answer (score 4):

```
    <table>
<tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black">
<td>abc</td><td>abc</td>
<tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black">
<td>def</td><td>def</td>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks you. I add `colspan="100%"` in my case: `<tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black"><td colspan="100%"></td></tr>`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100px; height:50px;
                   line-height:50px; letter-spacing:96px;
                   text-decoration: line-through;">
        &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

or in case u change ur mind about the graphics:

```
td.emptyCell {
    background-image: dot.gif; /* 1x1 px, whatever color u want */
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0% 50%;
}
```

Comment: The top one is an interesting hack, but doesn't quite work for my current situation. In order for it to work, I have to have an endless amount of `&nbsp` - which gets untidy real quick :) As for the second solution....I am on the fence with that one. Still trying to not use a graphic. We'll see how long I hold out though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me is defining css properties at column level and defining colspan as the number of columns in the table

HTML -

```
<tr class="border_bottom">
    <td colspan="6"></td>
</tr>
```

CSS -

```
tr.border_bottom td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
    color: #707070;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way for tables without using any image:

```
<style>
.dotted{
width:10px;height:50px;
line-height:50px;letter-spacing:96px;
text-decoration: line-through;text-decoration-style:dashed;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><span>Additional Charges</span></td>
        <td class="dotted">
        &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td><span>INR 3000.00</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```